# How do i get list of sended emails by myself (via AWS-SES)

Tags: email, amazon-ses

i want recipient and title of sended mails. Is't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the [current SES API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/APIReference/).

EDIT: you can always implement a record yourself, but AWS does not make their outbound queue log available to you to search/list.